# Linking an existing account from Yahoo to another from Facebook?

Tags: support, openid, login, facebook, yahoo

I normally use Yahoo to login on SO, but I'm too lazy to type in the password everytime, so I decided to use Facebook. The thing is: whenever I login with Facebook I go to a totally different account. I tried adding it to the existing account but it didn't work. The reputation goes to 1, but when I click on my profile link it goes to the actual profile I use with Yahoo.

How can I have the two accounts working together?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your account settings and try clicking on "add openid" link.  That lets you associate more openids to your existing account.  (So, you'll login with your primary account, click on this link and log into the secondary account.)  After that you can log in with either openid to access your account.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually have created two accounts (disregarding the clear message not to), you'll have to email team@stackoverflow.com to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you already did this, but I just want to make sure:

1. On your Stack Overflow profile, click "Change OpenID"
2. Click "Login to Facebook"
3. If you haven't already, log in to Facebook
4. Click "Allow"

---

If you did already do this or if it's not working, it sounds like when you click on your username, it takes you to your original profile even though it displays 1 rep. Is this correct?

Comment: Exactly. The accounts are not linked, for some reason. Right now i'm posting with the Facebook account.